# make use of User.Identity.Name when user first hits the site

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to run some code that makes use of User.Identity.Name,

I want to run that code when the user first enters the site.
(can be everytime they close the browser then reopen the site)

i tried putting it in Application_Start in the global.asax, but the User.Identity.Name name was returning null;

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on your description, you probably want to put your code in Session_Start, not Application_Start.  Session_Start is the event that fires when your application first sees each user.

Here's the list of events that are available in Global.asax: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication_events%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 6):

`User.Identity.Name` will not be null only when the user is authenticated. If you are using `Forms Authentication` this will happen when you call `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie`. If you are using Integrated Windows Authentication then normally the user will be automatically authenticated when he first requests the site. Normally you should not try to access it in `Application_Start`. You could write a custom authorization `Application_AuthenticateRequest` method which is fired when a security module establishes the identity of the user.

Comment: im using windows authentication

Comment: @raklos, OK, so try the `Application_AuthenticateRequest` event. It will be fired for each request.